# Better tools for introspection of our reviewing

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

I'm pretty new to a few review queues, so I've been checking up on how the consensus goes on them and whether I'm deviating from consensus so that I'm not reviewing incorrectly. I found this helpful particular because I noticed I was being too lenient on tag edits, so I've decided to skip them unless I'm specifically familiar with the topics being discussed in the question.

My actual request is, can re-investigating these results be made easier? The way I had to do it was by opening each review in an individual tab and then reading through the results from there. There's nowhere that the information is summarised or counted up. The best I can get is a count of how many I accepted and rejected, however that doesn't inform about whether or not others agreed with me or which reviews I deviated from the others.

I'm aware that there could be a lot of work in this request but I think it would be valuable to offer some level, because as far as I can tell the current system isn't in any way designed for this functionality and I'd like the addition to be considered (assuming it hasn't been already).

Comment: There is a similar feature request over on MSE where I wrote an [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248338/adding-the-consensus-to-reviews-history/251508#251508) that uses a userscript for your review history page to show how you did against your peers.

Comment: @rene That's great, I'll set that up thanks. It's a shame it looks like that post didn't get much of an official response.

Comment: There are a lot of feature requests and bugs across the network. The complete team would need to spend several weeks to analyze and respond to all of them...so they simply don't try... give it [6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)...